# How can I get the data of $album->from?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am getting album information by above scripts. How can I get the data of `$album->from`?

```
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    if($response=='')   {   echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";    }

     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url_albums = "https://graph.facebook.com/10150293277371173?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];
     $albums = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url_albums));
     }     

    ("token " . $params['access_token']);
    echo $albums_id=$albums->id; echo "</br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the Facebook API the Album object has access to the following fields:

> ```
> > id from name description location link cover_photo privacy count type
> > created_time updated_time
> ```

So what happens when you do:

```
echo $albums->from;
```

Comment: I want to get           
  1-"name": "Aston Ma", 
  2-"id": "693406172"

from
  "comments": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "10150241465236173_19727644", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Aston Ma", 
          "id": "693406172"
        }, 
        "message": "姨丈帶小b sir 滑梯~", 
        "can_remove": true, 
        "created_time": "2011-11-20T07:22:46+0000"
      }
    ],

Comment: var_dump() the $albums object and see what you actually got, and then have a look at the API